# How to create a Javascript onclick loop?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to create a toogle, where if the arrow is at 0 deg, it rotates, and if it's at 90deg, it rotates back to 0deg. However, at the moment, it is rotating on the first click, where the arrow is set to 90deg, but not on the second clcik to turn it back. Why?

```
    function togglepage() {
        if (document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform = "rotate(0deg)") {
            document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)") {
            document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform = "rotate(-90deg)";
            document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
        }
    }
```

Comment: An *equals comparison* is two equal signs `==` not one. See your `if` statement conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions are not correct, you need use '==' like

```
if (document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform == "rotate(0deg)")
```

Correct function is like that --

```
function togglepage() {
        if (document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform == "rotate(0deg)" || document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform == "") {
            document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform == "rotate(90deg)") {
            document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform = "";
        }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");

function togglepage(toggle) {
    console.log(toggle);
    switch(toggle.style.transform){
        case "":
        case "rotate(180deg)":  
        case "rotate(0deg)":
            toggle.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
        break;
        case "rotate(90deg)":
            toggle.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
        break;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

https://codepen.io/dkreativetech/pen/yLeEKoY

HTML CODE

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button">
        DROPDOWN
        <div class="caret">❯</div>
    </button>
</div>
```

jQuery CODE

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $(".caret").toggleClass("active");
})
```

CSS CODE

```
.dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 6px 20px 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.dropdown-toggle .caret {
    margin-left: 10px
}

.dropdown-toggle .caret.active {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```